# Apache poi class builds in Intellij but not with Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I have added a Spreadsheet class to a project in Intellij 2017 that uses the Apache Poi library. At first I was having problems compiling the code and getting it to run in Intellij. It appears to have been a dependency problem because I added Apache Poi 3.11 and then went back to 3.16 and it somehow would be able to resolve class symbols that it couldn't earlier. My first question is why did that work?

The real issue now is I am trying to build the project with Maven and Maven is also unable to resolve class and method symbols like getCellTypeEnum(), CellType and CellCopyPolicy as if it is trying to use an older version of poi and poi-ooxml.

I've tried adding both 3.11 and 3.16 as dependencies, just 3.11, just 3.16, for both poi and poi-ooxml. I've looked in .m2 and the libraries for all versions of poi are present.

This is my pom, as you might be able to tell, I started just throwing stuff in there hoping to get those symbols to resolve but they are clearly poi objects and also from what I can tell maven uses the most recent version of any dependency so using older stuff at the same time doesn't work.

**Edit:** Updated pom to include poi-scratchpad and changed order of dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>versionFinderUI</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.web.crawler.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

This is the output from the maven build. I also tried building from maven 
directly in the command line and got the same result.

**Edit:** I have changed the order of dependencies and added poi-scratchpad and am now down to 3 compilation errors, output shown below.

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING]  [WARNING] Some problems
>   were encountered while building the effective model for
>   groupId:versionFinderUI:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
>   'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
>   unique: org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar -> version 3.16 vs 3.11 @ line
>   41, column 21 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix
>   these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
>   [WARNING]  [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no
>   longer support building such malformed projects. [WARNING]  [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building versionFinderUI 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @
>   versionFinderUI --- [INFO] Deleting
>   C:\Users\jearl\Documents\Tasks\DevolpementFunTime\source\repos\versionFinderUI\target
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) @ versionFinderUI --- [WARNING] Using platform
>   encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is
>   platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 4 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ versionFinderUI
>   --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build
>   is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling 15 source files to
>   C:\Users\jearl\Documents\Tasks\DevolpementFunTime\source\repos\versionFinderUI\target\classes
>   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>   [WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [WARNING]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:
>   C:\Users\jearl\Documents\Tasks\DevolpementFunTime\source\repos\versionFinderUI\src\main\java\com\web\crawler\model\Spreadsheet.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. [WARNING]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. [WARNING]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/ScraperModule.java:
>   C:\Users\jearl\Documents\Tasks\DevolpementFunTime\source\repos\versionFinderUI\src\main\java\com\web\crawler\model\ScraperModule.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. [WARNING]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/ScraperModule.java:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. [INFO] 4 warnings  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:[126,42]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   copyCellFrom(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy)
>   location: class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:[212,38]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   copyCellFrom(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy)
>   location: class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:[301,21]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   method getCellTypeEnum()   location:
>   variable cell of type org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell [INFO] 3
>   errors  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 3.881 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-07-18T07:24:25-06:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/203M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project versionFinderUI: Compilation failure:
>   Compilation failure: [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:[126,42]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method
>   copyCellFrom(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy)
>   [ERROR] location: class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:[212,38]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method
>   copyCellFrom(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy)
>   [ERROR] location: class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/jearl/Documents/Tasks/DevolpementFunTime/source/repos/versionFinderUI/src/main/java/com/web/crawler/model/Spreadsheet.java:[301,21]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method getCellTypeEnum() [ERROR]
>   location: variable cell of type org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of
>   the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven
>   using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For
>   more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
>   the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**Edit:** It seems the problem resolved itself just like with Intellij. After messing around with the order of dependencies and adding stuff it didn't need, waiting a day, and adding nothing new the next day, it built. I'll leave this question up in case someone has an answer for why that would happen.

Comment: I think you've got the wrong package - you need things like `org.apache.poi` on the front

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "on the front"? Do you mean to change the order of dependencies? I have now done that and added poi-scratchpad and I'm down to only three compilation errors! I'll update the question.